# Python output not what i would think will happen (Functional Programming)

Tags: python, string, list, lambda, functional-programming

I am trying to output the  vowel letters (Case as typed) of an input and pipe it thorugh python using "Functional Programming".

```
def bob(word):
    return list(map(lambda x:x in ['a', 'e','i','o','u'], word.lower().strip()))

bob('Hello')
[False, True, False, False, True]
```

Although the output as seen above was not what i was expecting. Any ideas?

Comment: Please make sure that the indentation is correct. Also, you should use `filter` function instead of `map`

Comment: Fixed Indent. The filter function did give the desired output. i will need to remove my word.lower() to get the desired upper and lower case.

Comment: The output is perfectly alright. What did you expect?

Comment: If i remove word.lower() and change the word to 'Aloha' it does not see the Upper case A.

Comment: Fun fact: you can do `x.lower() in 'aeiou'` instead of what you did (use a string instead of a list).

Comment: Cody. That x.lower() worked on the output. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Becuase of the help in the comments i got the output i was looking for.

what worked for me was adding the .lower() to x in the functional programming style as well as using filter.

```
def bob(word):
    return list(filter(lambda x:x.lower() in ['a','e','i','o','u'], word.strip()))
```

This made the output view the upper case A within Aloha.

```
bob('Aloha')
['A', 'o', 'a']
```

Thanks Guys!

Comment: It has nothing to do with the `lower` call. In this code, you used `filter`; in the code in the question, you used `map`. `map` and `filter` do completely different things.

Comment: Yes my mistake. Although when i used .lower() after word it would output the A in Aloha as a lower.. when its x.lower() it will output a uppercase A. Thats what i was trying to get at.